# Forward specific ports on virtual interface to docker

Tags: iptables, docker

I have created a virtual interface on my enp1s0 called virtual0. enp1s0 is going to be configured to be behind the router. Virtual0 will be configured to be accessable to the outside world. I am running some docker instances, that i use locally on the network, but i want to expose some of them to the outside world. Example i would not like my samba instance to be exposed but i want my openvpn instance exposed.

I have successfully gotten two ip addresses, but i cannot only allow access to some docker instances through the ip enp1s0 uses.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying ip in the -p option allows you to use a specific ip address